# Remove a stopwords from strings: why do I have an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to apply a stopwords list in a text, but before I need to take some words off this list. The problem is that when I apply in my text, the result is an infinite loop

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))
negation = ['n', 'pas', 'ne']
remove_words = [word for word in stop_words if word not in negation]
stopwords_regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, remove_words)))
replace_stopwords = stopwords_regex.sub('', text)

print(replace_stopwords)
```

It's difficult to give an example because with one phrase it works, but with  a collection of many strings, the stopwords are removed but the program never stops.

Comment: "the stopwords are removed but the program never stops" So, the `print` at the end is reached, but _then_ it does not stop? How else do you determine that the words are removed?

Comment: How many stop words do you have? Maybe compilng or applying the regex is just slow. Btw, the `\b` around the `|` should not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `tokenize` your corpus using the `nltk.RegexpTokenizer` then remove your modified `stopwords`

```
from nltk import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

content_french = ("John Richard Bond explique pas le rôle de l'astronomie.")
# initialize & apply tokenizer
toknizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'''\w'|\w+|[^\w\s]''')
content_french_token = toknizer.tokenize(content_french)
# initialize & modify stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))
negation = {'n', 'pas', 'ne'}
stop_words = set([wrd for wrd in stop_words if wrd not in negation])
# modify your text
content_french = " ".join([wrd for wrd in content_french_token if wrd not in stop_words])
```